# Getting ValueError as response to http request in Django framework

Tags: python, django

When i access this url:

```
http://localhost:8000/ProjectOverview/proj_view/15/
```

Django tells me that the format is in complete:

```
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/ProjectOverview/proj_view/15/
Django Version:     1.3.1
Exception Type:     ValueError
Exception Value:    incomplete format

Exception Location:     /home/projects/bruens_erp/ProjectOverview/views.py in proj_view, line 11
```

My urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^ProjectOverview/$', 'ProjectOverview.views.index'),
    url(r'^ProjectOverview/login/$', 'ProjectOverview.views.login'),
    url(r'^ProjectOverview/proj_view/(?P<cust>\d+)/$', 'ProjectOverview.views.proj_view'),
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

My views.py:

```
# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Index.... please login")

def login(request):
    return HttpResponse("login page")

def proj_view(request, cust):
    return HttpResponse("project overview for cust: %." % cust)
```

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your % become %s (if it's an string) or %d (if it's an integer):

```
def proj_view(request, cust):
    return HttpResponse("project overview for cust: %s." % cust)
```

See [python string-formatting](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/typesseq-strings.html).

Comment: Hmm yes, just saw the typo.. goddamn dyslexias